# Dynamic textbox and dynamic label

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, textbox, label

I have created 3 dynamic texbox. At the run time i wanna enter some values in that textbox. if click the button then the entered textboxes value should be display in one dynamic label control.

please help me with some samples

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 1):

USe Page.FindControl to access to dynamically created controls

Answer (score 0):

You can do it client side, assuming your using jquery something like:

```
<span name="display" id="display"></span>
<input name="text1" id="text1" />
<input name="text2" id="text2" />
<input name="text3" id="text3" />

<input type="button" id="button1" />

<script>
    $("#button1").click(function() { 
        $("#display").html($("#text1").val() + $("#text2").val() + $("#text3").val());
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in asp.net

.CS file

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{

    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.ID = "mylbl";
    lbl.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
    form1.Controls.Add(lbl);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "txt" + i;
        form1.Controls.Add(txt);
    }

}



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = form1.FindControl("mylbl") as Label;
        lbl.Text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            TextBox txt = form1.FindControl("txt" + i) as TextBox;


            lbl.Text += txt.Text;
        }
    }
```

.aspx File

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>

    </form>
```